# How to center column names in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to center the column names, as they currently are left aligned.

The code I am using is:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0pt}} lcccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & N & \vtop{\hbox{\strut Green}\hbox{\strut bond issuers (1)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut Non-green}\hbox{\strut bond issuers (2)}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut p-value}\hbox{\strut (diff. in means) (3)}}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Log(assets) & 001 & 1.621 & 6.666 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
 &  & (0.999) & (0.025) &  \\ 
Return on assets & 1321 & 0.099 & 0.000 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
 &  & (0.888) & (0.101) &  \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add stuff in order for it to even be able to compile. And what we add might be different from what you have in your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

It is produced using the `makecell` and the `booktabs` package. The `thead` macro from the `makecell` package allows to insert manual linebreak in the table header and it also centers the content both horizontally and vertically (however different alignment is also possible with an optional argument).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \thead{N} & \thead{Green\\bond issues\\(1)} & \thead{Non-green\\bond issues\\(2)} & \thead{p-value\\(diff. in means)\\(3)}
    \\\midrule
    Log(assets) & 001 & 1.621 & 6.666 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
    &  & (0.999) & (0.025) &  \\ 
    Return on assets & 1321 & 0.099 & 0.000 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
    &  & (0.888) & (0.101) &  
    \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more complex solution, but it can serve for more complex tables of similar sort:

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
        }
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

 
\begin{document}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {caption title},
  label = {tab:???},
note{} = {***: some explanation},
                    ]{colspec = {l c
                              *{2}{S[table-format={(}1.3{)}]}
                                   S[table-format=1.3{***}]},
                       colsep = {4pt},
                     row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                 row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=3pt},
                      measure = vbox
                     }
    \toprule
    & N     & {{{Green\\ bond issuers\\ (1)}}}
                & {{{Non-green\\ bond issuers\\ (2)}}}
                            & {{{$p$-value\\ {(diff. in means)}\\ (3)}}}   
                                    \\
    \midrule
Log(assets) 
    & 001   & 1.621     & 6.666     & 0.000\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &       & (0.999)   & (0.025)   &                       \\
Return on assets 
    & 1321  & 0.099     & 0.000     & 0.000\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &       & (0.888)   & (0.101)   &                       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
A solution with improved table notes (as was suggest the package `tabularray` author on my inquire on *github*). Now the table's notes cab be organized as list defined by  `enimitem` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % <---
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\NewTblrTheme{itemize}% you can select different name of theme
{
\DefTblrTemplate{note}{default}{%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\tablewidth}%
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
    \MapTblrNotes {
      \item[\UseTblrTemplate{note-tag}{default}{:}]
      \UseTblrTemplate{note-target}{default}
      \UseTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}
                  }
  \end{enumerate}            }% end of template
} % end of theme
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
        }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
{
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{talltblr}[
  theme = itemize,
caption = {Caption title},
  label = {tab:talltblr},
 note{**}  = {first explanation},
 note{***} = {second explanation},
                    ]{colspec = {l c
                              *{2}{S[table-format={(}1.3{)}]}
                                   S[table-format=1.3{***}]},
                       colsep = {4pt},
                     row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                 row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=3pt},
                      measure = vbox
                     }
    \toprule
    & N     & {{{Green\\ bond issuers\\ (1)}}}
                & {{{Non-green\\ bond issuers\\ (2)}}}
                            & {{{$p$-value\\ {(diff. in means)}\\ (3)}}}
                                    \\
    \midrule
Log (assets)
    & 001   & 1.621     & 6.666     & 0.000\TblrNote{**}    \\
    &       & (0.999)   & (0.025)   &                       \\
Return on assets
    & 1321  & 0.099     & 0.000     & 0.000\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &       & (0.888)   & (0.101)   &                       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this effect.  `\multicolumn{1}{p{...}}{...}` will replace the `c` column with a `p` column, but you have to specify a width.  You can put a tabular inside the tabular.  But the easiest and least confusing solution is to simply divide the text into three rows (two rows would be too wide for the page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}% \extracolsep is only used with tabular*
\\[-1.8ex]% adds \arrarystretch\baselineskip - 1.8ex
\hline\hline
\\[-1.8ex]
 & N & Green & Non-green & p-value \\
 & & bond issuers & bond issuers & (diff. in means) \\
 & & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
\hline
\\[-1.8ex] 
Log(assets) & 001 & 1.621 & 6.666 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
 &  & (0.999) & (0.025) &  \\ 
Return on assets & 1321 & 0.099 & 0.000 & 0.000\textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered \textasteriskcentered  \\ 
 &  & (0.888) & (0.101) &  \\ 
\hline 
\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```